# Different size of image using cell.imageView.image. Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, imageview, size, cell

Is it possible to set all the image in the same size? I tried to use cell.imageView?.frame.size.width = something. But, it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.imageView!.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cell.imageView!.clipsToBounds = true
    let imageData = try! resultsImageFileArray[indexPath.row].getData()
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    cell.imageView?.image = image

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.resultsNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.message3Array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not change the properties of `cell.imageView` field when you use `UITableViewCell` because `imageView` is read-only property in this case. The easiest way to achieve the result in this case is to create subclass of `UITableViewCell` and use it to customize what you need in `layoutSubviews` method for example like this:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    // Here you can customize the appearance of your cell
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // Customize imageView like you need
        self.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(10,0,40,40)
        self.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        // Costomize other elements
        self.textLabel?.frame = CGRectMake(60, 0, self.frame.width - 45, 20)
        self.detailTextLabel?.frame = CGRectMake(60, 20, self.frame.width - 45, 15)
    }
}
```

And inside your `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` function you can only replace cell object creation from  `UITableViewCell` to `CustomTableViewCell`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: CustomTableViewCell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.imageView!.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cell.imageView!.clipsToBounds = true
    let imageData = try! resultsImageFileArray[indexPath.row].getData()
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    cell.imageView?.image = image

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.resultsNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.message3Array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hi. I know how to do it in that way. But, I am wondering is there any simple method that can set all the image have same width

Comment: @PakHoCheung Unfortunately there is no easy way, because `imageView` from `UITableViewCell` object is read-only property and you can't change it params or set it your custom `UIImageView` object.

Comment: I am thinking is there any way to use something like using layer or something like that to make all the images look same size?

Comment: Last question. When I test it in my phone, I see the line between cells have different lengths. How can I make the line all the way from left to right?

Comment: @PakHoCheung You did something wrong, I have created at an empty project with exactly the same code in the answer, and I have everything displayed properly

Comment: @PakHoCheung As for the separator. You can change it working with `separatorInset` property of your `UITableView`. For example try add this line of code: `tableView.separatorInset.left = 10` inside `viewDidLoad` method of your `UITableViewController` class.

Comment: Shouldn't you be registering the cell class and calling dequeueReusableCell?